# How do I pronounce/Translate this last name: マッキェネン into english?

Tags: translation, pronunciation, names

I'm translating this book, and the character's full name pops up as " クロウディア＝マッキェネン". I managed to translate the first name as Claudia, but I don't know if I should use McCunnen, McCullen, or some other possible translation for her last name, and thusly I am in need for some advice.

Comment: Is this her? https://phantomrequiemforthephantomanime.fandom.com/wiki/Claudia_McCunnen

Comment: Yes, and no. Phantom Requiem: for the Phantom came out seven years after the book was published, and PR:ftP is unfortunately rife with mistranslations when it comes to character names, so I unfortunately can't use it insofar as accurately spelling translated character names in the novella (which is set in the same universe/storyline).

Comment: 「マッキェネン」って言おうとしても「マッケネン」みたいにしかならない・・・

Comment: @Chocolate　英語に何が　”みたいにしかならない” をイコールか?

Comment: "I try to say マッキェネン but I end up sounding like マッケネン" とか。。 or maybe "I can't read マッキェネン without sounding like マッケネン" かな・・

Comment: あら、今に見てです！　ありがとうございます、Chocolate-さん。

Comment: Just from the kana, I'm leaning more towards //makːʲenen//, which sounds more Italian to me than anything Scots or Irish, ruling out _Mc-_ or _Mac-_ names.  Then again, names -- especially non-Japanese names as used in manga and similar media -- often bear little resemblance to those of the real world.  _McCunnen_, for instance, I'd pronounce much closer to //mə'kʌnən//, and _Claudia_ more like //klɔːdi.ə//: if she were nicknamed by the first syllable of her given name, that would be homophonous with _Claw_, not クロ.  But anyway...  :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a screenshot of the [official site of the X360 port](http://www.phantom360.net/#character) (Flash-only):

[image]

So she is officially **Claudia McCunnen**.

ネ always corresponds to the "N" consonant, not "L". Even without this site, we can say McCullen is not really a valid transliteration.

Comment: Apparently I misheard then misremembered her name in my playthrough of the original DVD game a few weeks back, when Scythe (with his surprisingly believable pseudo-German accent) says her last name at the very start of the game. I double checked last night, and it is 100% actually McCunnen, my ears and memory are to blame for the McCullen ha ha.